# how to use external libraries in ROS code?

Tags: ros, rosdep, qt, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We have a GUI that was developed using Qt and now we are planning to use ROS in our code. Is it possible to integrate ROS with our existing Qt code?

In a general sense, how do we use external libraries such as Qt, OpenGL and **user built libraries** with ROS code?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9430/how-to-use-external-libraries-in-ros-code?/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not in the general sense, but rather specific to your question,
you can have a look at [RGBD-SLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM) which uses qt and opengl. The CMakeLists.txt and manifest can be found [here](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2)

Check out [main.cpp](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/kinetic/src/main.cpp), [qtros.h](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/kinetic/src/qtros.h) and [qtros.cpp](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/kinetic/src/qtros.cpp) to see how we moved the ROS spinning into a subclass of QThread to run the callbacks in parallel to the Qt application's event loop.

(**Update:** The above links used to point to the repository http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/freiburg_kinect-experimental/rgbdslam which no longer exists and have been updated to point at the github rgbdslam_v2 repo which may or may not illustrate what is described)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-16**:
great, this worked for qt. I changed my CMakelits.txt similar to the one in the package and it works perfectly. I am posting a small description on how to do it in the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For OpenGl I just add the dependency in the manifest:

```
    <rosdep name="opengl"/>
```

It is solved in the core rosdep.yaml file ([rosdep wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep))
My CMakelists.txt entry looks like this:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} X11 m GL GLU glut)
```

In addition to the original ROS CMakelists. I assume you can do the same for QT. (if not I'm interested to know)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-16**:
@snorri: I did create a rosdep.yaml. I used the rosdep.yaml from geometry stack. I changed the line "ubuntu: libglut3-dev" with "ubuntu: libglut", "ubuntu: freeglut", "ubuntu: libglut3". None of them worked so I ended up changing Cmakelists.txt file

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-03-16**:
If no abstraction exists for glut, simply create your own rosdep.yaml and put it in at your stack level (look at other stack rosdep.yaml's for examples).

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-03-16**:
$ROS_ROOT/rosdep.yaml though is the last line of defence in trying to find the abstraction-conversion. The first rosdep.yaml any package looks in is inside the package itself, if it can't satisfy an abstraction there, it then looks in the stack rosdep.yaml, then finally $ROS_ROOT/rosdep.yaml.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-03-16**:
Things like the 'opengl' above are abstractions for a package name. As koenbuys mentioned, these abstractions are converted to real package names for each distro in the rosdep.yaml files. You can find the abstraction and conversions for opengl in $ROS_ROOT/rosdep.yaml.

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-16**:
@KoenBuys: by specifying opengl it worked but I got undefined references for glut functions. So I also added rosdep name="glut", it didn't help. So I manually added the target_link_libraries statement with glut to my CMakelists.txt file. Do you think this will create issues in future?